# Hierarchical data into array

Tags: php

I need some logic for the following problem, but can't get my head around it. Basically I have some data like the following array

```
array(
    array('name' => 'Test1',
          'hierarchy'=> '1'),
    array('name' => 'Test2',
          'hierarchy'=> '1.1'),
    array('name' => 'Test3',
          'hierarchy'=> '1.2'),
    array('name' => 'Test4',
          'hierarchy'=> '1.2.1')
)
```

Now I would like to output an array in such a way that

```
$array[1] = 'Test1';
$array[1][2][1] = 'Test4';
```

Tried dynamic variable naming and dynamically creating multidimensional arrays, but both dont seem to work.

Comment: You said, "Tried dynamic variable naming and dynamically creating multidimensional arrays, but both dont seem to work." - show us your code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not possible.

For `$array[1] = 'Test1';` `$array[1]` needs to be a string, but for `$array[1][2][1] = 'Test4';` it needs to be an array.

You could do something like this:

```
$array[1]['text'] = 'Test1';
$array[1][2][1]['text'] = 'Test4';
```

Here's code for that:

```
$result = array();

foreach ($input as $entry)
{
    $path_components = explode('.', $entry['hierarchy']);

    $pointer =& $result;
    foreach ($path_components as $path_component)
        $pointer =& $pointer[$path_component];

    $pointer['text'] = $entry['name'];

    unset($pointer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't absolutely need an array, you can create a class and extend [ArrayClass](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) or if you need only the array access, you can also implement [ArrayAccess](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php).
From there, you can parse through your data and return the required values for your application.

Comment: Valid idea, but it would require some sort of sorted map inside so we wouldn't have to search the proper value everytime. Well, and an array in php is a sorted hash map, so this would be kind of redundant.